# Max execution time php.ini

Tags: php

You can override max_execution_time by doing set_time_limit(0).

But what is the setting called where the script just stops after a long time?
In one of my servers it stops after 1 hour, in another server 50 minutes, but i cannot figure out which setting this is?

Comment: are you asking where in php.ini is the max_execution_time set?

Comment: no, im talking about where this "true" max execution setting is. if you override max_execution_time with set_time_limit(0), it will still stop running after som time. its this limit i wonder where you can find.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons it is possible that you can not override set_time_limit() for higher value.

[PHP set_time_limit() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#refsect1-function.set-time-limit-notes)